# What is the difference between \n and the enter key in C?

Tags: c

The ASCII value of enter is 13 and that of `'\n'` is 10. They both get us to the next line. Why are their ASCII values different?

Answer (score 6):

The two characters are CR (carriage return, 13) and LF (line feed, 10) and either one (or both) can be used to represent a newline depending on the convention used by the operating system. Citing Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline):

> Systems based on ASCII or a compatible character set use either LF
>   (Line feed, '\n', 0x0A, 10 in decimal) or CR (Carriage return, '\r',
>   0x0D, 13 in decimal) individually, or CR followed by LF (CR+LF,
>   '\r\n', 0x0D0A). These characters are based on printer commands: The
>   line feed indicated that one line of paper should feed out of the
>   printer thus instructed the printer to advance the paper one line, and
>   a carriage return indicated that the printer carriage should return to
>   the beginning of the current line. Some rare systems, such as QNX
>   before version 4, used the ASCII RS (record separator, 0x1E, 30 in
>   decimal) character as the newline character.

The same article indicates which convention is used by which OS:

> - LF:    Multics, Unix and Unix-like systems (Linux, OS X, FreeBSD, AIX, Xenix, etc.), BeOS, Amiga, RISC OS and others.
> - CR:    Commodore 8-bit machines, Acorn BBC, ZX Spectrum, TRS-80, Apple II family, Mac OS up to version 9 and OS-9
> - RS:    QNX pre-POSIX implementation.
> - 0x9B:  Atari 8-bit machines using ATASCII variant of ASCII. (155 in decimal)
> - LF+CR: Acorn BBC and RISC OS spooled text output.
> - CR+LF: Microsoft Windows, DEC TOPS-10, RT-11 and most other early non-Unix and non-IBM OSes, CP/M, MP/M, DOS (MS-DOS, PC DOS, etc.), Atari TOS, OS/2, Symbian OS, Palm OS, Amstrad CPC

Answer (score 5):

Enter is a key, not a character, so it doesn't really have a value. In some systems there is also a Return key and these keys may one give the *line feed* (ASCII 10), the other *carriage return* (ASCII 13). In some systems they give out only one of them.

The *line feed* character is the only one that will get to the next line, but the original meaning is just that: go to the next line, not go to the *beginning* of next line. The original meaning of *carriage return* is go to the beginning of the line.

This means that some systems require both characters to actually go to the beginning of next line (like Windows), some systems use only one.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `\n` takes you to the new line. For example:

```
printf("hello"); (press enter)
printf("world");
Output: helloworld
```

When you use `\n` in code:

```
printf("hello");
printf("\nworld");
Output: hello
        world
```