# for x in text - how does python know x is supposed to read a line, not a word, a letter, ...?

Tags: python, for-loop

When you use a for loop in python, for example to read a txt line by line, you'd maybe write:

```
txt = open("SomeTextFile.txt", "r")
for x in txt:
    print (x)
```

Now, my question is: How does python "know" that it is supposed to read one line? Why isn't it one letter or one word?

Comment: is txt a file or a string?

Comment: Its because under the covers, the for loop treats `txt` to be iterable and the object that `txt` refers to knows how to iterate.

Comment: txt is a file that was opened by using open("filename", "r")

Comment: It would have been better if you had stated that in the question to begin with.

Comment: If you are indeed asking "why?" then the answer is: because it is implemented like that here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/345572a1a0263076081020524016eae867677cac/Lib/_pyio.py#L579

Comment: @quamrana That is true, but because I didn't know the answer to the question already I didn't know that this would matter

Comment: It was obvious that we ought to know because you don't define `txt` in your code. You should treat the people who are here to help you a bit like compilers/interpreters. They need to have everything defined up front.

Comment: @quamran Yes, I am sorry, I just kinda thought txt would be enough to know it's a txt file but it of course isn't. Hope it won't happen again. One second I will edit the question

Comment: The answer below from Krishna shows how programmers here could think that a variable like `txt` could equally be a text string, a list (of strings) or an open text file. However, as the answer shows, the same code serves equally well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the type of `txt`, in general for loop gets one item from the pool for each iteration

```
>>> txt = 'bla'
>>> for x in txt: print(x)
... 
b
l
a
>>> txt = ['bla', 'foo', 'bar']
>>> for x in txt: print(x)
... 
bla
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `txt` is either a string read from a file, or a file object (something you created using `open()`).

By default, lines are separated by a newline (character `'\n'`). While you can think of these as what gets typed when you press the 'Enter' or 'Return' key, [it's not exactly true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026952/what-is-the-difference-between-n-and-the-enter-key-in-c).

In your code, Python is implicitly searching for `'\n'`, and each time it finds one, it marks that as an element. You could very well use the [`.split(some_string_goes_here)`](https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split) method on a string and split by spaces or whatever you choose.

Many of these "lines" (or words, or whatever) are "grouped" as an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-iterable), so the for loop can access one at a time.

Source: https://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: Newlines are never separated by only `\r` as they will be rewritten by the next string. So `print("Hello\rWorld")` will output `World`. `\n\r` is the common usage of newlining because some OS's do not return carriages automatically so it's made for full compatibility for all OS's. It's redundant for Windows and most of Unix systems, so usage of '\n` mostly won't bring you in any trouble

Comment: @sudden_appearance I actually realised that after re-reading my answer and fact-checking an assumption. Could you please tell me if the current edit/version is correct? Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `txt = open(<filename>)`

You may think of a

```
for x in txt:
    ...
```

as

```
iterator = iter(txt)

while True:
    try:
        x = next(iterator)
        ...
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

`iter(txt)` will return iterator that iterates over file lines, so that's why you are iterating over txt lines